# Не показывает баннер ADMOB

Tags: java, android

Баннер на устройствах с нормальным разрешением работает хорошо.
Но на телефонах с низким разрешением он вообще не появляется.

Вот логи и xml

```
I/GMPM﹕ App measurement is starting up
E/GMPM﹕ getGoogleAppId failed with status: 10
E/GMPM﹕ Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled
```

и

```
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ Google Play services out of date.  Requires 8115000 but found 6599034
 E/GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ GooglePlayServices not available due to error 2
```

и

```
   W/Ads﹕ Not enough space to show ad. Needs 320x50 dp, but only has 288x420 dp.
```

here id main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/gradient"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.nesususu.nes.app.onResume">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout20"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:gravity="top|center_horizontal"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timeField2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="73dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:shadowColor="@color/bright_foreground_disabled_material_dark"
        android:shadowDx="0"
        android:shadowDy="0"
        android:shadowRadius="24"
        android:text="00:00:00"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#06ff00"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:theme="@style/Animation.AppCompat.DropDownUp" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="86dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout16"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnExit"
        android:layout_width="91dp"
        android:layout_height="86dp"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btnexitcode"
        android:gravity="center" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout16"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout16"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"></com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</LinearLayout>
```

build app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'com.nesususu.nes.app'
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 3
    versionName "1.2"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
productFlavors {
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'

}
```

Я пробовал перемещать сам баннер в разные места, но эффект тот же.Все работает на Sony Xperia и Sumsung galzy tab e, но на  Sumsung SM-G360H с разрешением 480 x 800 нет..

Comment: проблема не в разрешении, а в физическом размере экрана (dp). Также в логаг написано о несоответствии версии Google Play Services

Comment: Так я прлшу полщнния,я не понял,проблему можно решить? В других приложениях реклама то както работает

Comment: если бы знал - написал бы как. А так - только могу интерпритировать сообщения об ошибке человеческим языком

Comment: И на том спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Not enough space to show ad. Needs 320x50 dp, but only has 288x420 dp
```

Какие еще вопросы?

UPD. В теории в вас резрешение 480x800, hdpi, т.е коеффициент 1.5
Значит размеры в dp у вас 320dp x 533dp, т.е. по ширине впритык хватит для баннера 320x50dp.

Лишнее место у вас сьедают вот эти отступы в коневом лаяуте:

```
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
```

Уберите их и все должно заработать.